# Sortable columns on Tablix with multiple header rows

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, sql-server-data-tools

I have a tablix control with multiple header rows.  There are no groupings; the extra rows are just for the visual effect of displaying information.

I've followed the instructions for [how to add Interactive Sort to a Table or Matrix](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627509.aspx).

I've gone to the textbox in the header (also tried doing the same to all three) and gone to properties:

[image: Properties]

And then enabled Interactive Sorting:

[image: Interactive Sort]

If I only have a single header row, it works and looks like this:

[image: Expected]

But it actually looks like this:

[image: Actual]

Can I add interactive sorting when there are multiple rows?

**Potential Workaround**: The only thing I thought of would be to add the sort fields as a parameter to the report and set the sorting at the Tablix level as an expression based off that.  But I like the organic look and feel of inline sorting.

Comment: What version of SSRS?

Comment: @TabAlleman using Data Tools 2010